A star subgraph of maximum order
Let $G$ be a simple graph. Is the order of an induced subgraph of $G$ which is a star graph and with maximum order, has a special name or known?

The central vertex of such a star would be a vertex of maximum degree in $G$. I would refer to this as a vertex of maximum degree together with its neighbourhood.

The maximal degree is often noted $\Delta$, so in your case, the order would be $\Delta+1$

@Mathieu Rundström Thank you very much! Sorry for the mistake. I mean the induced subgraph is a star. I edited the question.

@caduk Very sorry for my mistake. I edited the answer because I mean the induced subgraph.

I don't know if there is a particular terminology for this, but it is common to consider the classes of star-free graphs (or $K_{1,n}$-free graphs). Notably, the claw-free graphs are the graphs excluding $K_{1,3}$ as an induced subgraph.

Thanks for your guidance and help.
